# Managing users in Ruby on Rails (& ownership)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm somewhat of a Rails newbie, and am not quite sure what the convention is when tying users to their objects, such as documents. (And I now know how important it is to *go with conventions* in Rails)

So far, I have come up with 3 potential solutions in my head:

1. Making every document essentially a child of every user, using `has_many` and `belongs_to`
2. Giving every document an integer (`user_id`, or something along the lines of that) that ties it to the user. That way, whenever the user wants an index of their documents, I can identify all those that have the right ID.
3. It seems like there's some plugins that do user management completely in their own way that doesn't fit into any of the above.

Additionally, I plan on using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for user authentication and management. From my understanding, that seems to be the most popular/widely used authentication gem -- please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm somewhat of a Rails newbie

Welcome to the club, although some people bite, most are totally cool.

---

> tying users to their objects

You've already [answered your own question](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association)...

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :documents
end

#app/models/document.rb
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

If a user creates a document, surely that would mean that you'd have to associate `documents` to `users` via a `has_many` / `belongs_to` relationship...

--

To give you some context, you'll have to add the `user_id` [*foreign_key*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) to your `documents` table:

```
$ rails g migration AddUserForeignKeyToDocuments

#db/migrate/add_user_foreign_key_to_documents______.rb
class AddUserForeignKeyToDocuments < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      change_table :documents do |t| 
         t.references :user, index: true
      end
   end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```

This would allow something like the following (using the [`current_user` helper from `Devise`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers)):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :documents

#app/controllers/documents_controller
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @document = current_user.documents.new document_params
      @document.save
   end

   private

   def document_params
      params.require(:document).permit(.....)
   end
end
```

---

If you're unsure about user authentication, you should go with [`Devise`](https://gorails.com/episodes/user-authentication-with-devise), although there are other authentication gems such as [`sorcery`](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery)

Setting up `Devise` is simple:

```
#Gemfile
gem 'devise', '~> 3.5', '>= 3.5.3'

$ rails generate devise:install
$ rails generate devise User
$ rake db:migrate

#config/routes
devise_for :users

#app/controllers/documents_controller.rb
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

This will make it so only logged-in users can access `/documents` :)

Answer (score 1):

This is primarily an opinion-based question however I tend to see most projects using ActiveRecord's relations (e.g `has_many`, `belongs_to`).

Comment: Awesome. I appreciate the advice!

Answer (score 1):

you can use devise for authentification (or build an own login system [there is a railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1) and use [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) for authorization. some defining of abilities you will find in the [documentation](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities)
just for example

```
can :update, Article
```

or if user can just delete own stuff

```
can :read, Project, active: true, user_id: user.id
```

i would also use the ActiveRecord relation with `has_many` e.g. and `has_many through`